# Bookmarklet Javascript Array Leak?

Tags: javascript, arrays, bookmarklet

For my project, I am creating a bookmarklet which gives users tag options. I am passing an array in of the user's top tags and looping in javascript to generate all the options.

The problem is that the array is picking up rogue functions from the underlying page that are somehow making it into the array and as you can see in the image below: screwing up everything.

I've tried manually removing these by taking off the blocks by string length - but I discovered that in some cases (as in the case of wired magazine articles) the rogue functions has an open script tag which I am removing and thus breaking the bookmarklet.

Here is the code where I build the javascript array:

```
<?php foreach ($default_aspects as $aspect_id => $aspect_display) { ?>
  default_aspects['<?php echo $aspect_id; ?>'] = '<?php echo $aspect_display; ?>';
<?php } ?>
```

And here is the code where I print the array out:

```
html += '<div id="bml_category___" style="display:none; opacity:0;">';
  for (var i in default_aspects) {
    html += '<div class="bml_category_block___">' + default_aspects[i] + '</div>';
  };
```

You can see what this looks like (and the problem) here:
http://cl.ly/0W1Y0B0U1S210L1h2y2n

I guess there is some sort of leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is probably using a JavaScript framework, which modifies native objects. Use the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) method to filter out these methods.

I use `Object.hasOwnProperty.call(default_aspects, i)` instead of `default_aspects.hasOwnProperty(i)`, to make sure that a property named `hasOwnProperty` does not break your code.

```
html += '<div id="bml_category___" style="display:none; opacity:0;">';
for (var i in default_aspects) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(default_aspects, i)) {
        html += '<div class="bml_category_block___">' + default_aspects[i] + '</div>';
    }
};
```

If you've got a modern browser, it's easier to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var keys = Object.keys(default_aspects);
for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    html += '<div class="bml_category_block___">' + default_aspects[i] + '</div>'
}
```

Or, using [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
Object.keys(default_aspects).forEach(function(key) {
    html += '<div class="bml_category_block___">' + default_aspects[key] + '</div>'
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! I ended up reading this article, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html, and then simply creating my own object instead of running up against conflicting extensions of the Array object. Many thanks!